# hta - ajax call to php script on webserver

Tags: php, ajax, database, hta

I am thinking of writing a desktop HTA program.

However, at startup I would need to make 1 ajax php database call to a website, which will need a success element callback.

Is this possible? Would I need to overcome any crossbrowser issues? Would firewalls cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible - yes. See code below. Crossbrowser is not applicable in HTA -- you're always using the IE rendering engine. But I think you may mean cross-domain issues, which are also not applicable in HTA. Microsoft chose to disable all of the Javascript cross-domain protection because an HTA (HTML-Application) is treated as an application not a web page.

There are lots of considerations for firewalls, but it's unlikely that a firewall would block HTA AJAX calls more restrictively than HTML AJAX. If you have a web page that calls your PHP page, it will probably also work in HTA.  Good luck!

```
<html><head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var XHR = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 function callAjax(url){
   XHR.onreadystatechange=(callback);
   txtStatus.value += "opening: " + url + "\n";
   XHR.open("GET",url,true); //"POST" also works
   XHR.send(); // XHR.send("name1=value1&name2=value2");
 }

 function callback(){
   if(XHR.readystate == 4) txtStatus.value += "DONE\n" + XHR.responseText;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="callAjax(txtURL.value)">
  <textarea id=txtURL style="width:100%" rows=1>http://www.google.com</textarea>
  <textarea id=txtStatus style="width:100%" rows=20></textarea>
</body></html>
```